# RNN network: ValueError: Expected input batch_size (96) to match target batch_size (32)

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am implementing a simple recurrent neural network architecture for CIFAR10 image classification. I have also changed the batch size 512 to 1536 but it didn't work out. The input_size and sequence length is 32.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

all_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((32, 32)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465],
                         std=[0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010])]
)

train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, transform=all_transforms, download=True)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, transform=all_transforms, download=True)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

print(train_dataset)

input_size = 32
hidden_size = 64
num_layers = 2
num_classes = 10
sequence_length = 32


# Recurrent Neural Network (many-to-one)
# Fully connected neural network with one hidden layer
class SimpleRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(SimpleRNN, self).__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_dim, hidden_size=64, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64, 10)  # hidden dimension is output dimension

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(1, x.size(0), 64).to(device)
        out, _ = self.rnn(x, h0)
        out = out[:, -1, :]
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out


model = SimpleRNN(input_dim=input_size)
model.cuda()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.005, momentum=0.9)
total_step = len(train_loader)

epochs = 20

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.view(-1, 32, 32).cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda()

        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print("Epochs [{}/{}], Loss: {:4f}".format(epoch + 1, epochs, loss.item()))

# with torch.no_grad():
#     correct = 0
#     total = 0
#     for images, labels in train_loader:
#         images = images.reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).cuda()
#         labels = images.cuda()
#
#         outputs = model(images)
#         _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
#         total += labels.size(0)
#         correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
#
#     print('Accuracy of the network on the {} train images: {} %'.format(50000, 100 * correct / total))
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/278/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/278/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/tutorials/pytorch_simple_rrn.py", line 63, in <module>
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 961, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2468, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2261, in nll_loss
    raise ValueError('Expected input batch_size ({}) to match target batch_size ({}).'
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (96) to match target batch_size (32).
```

Answer (score 0):

You've resized your images incorrectly, they are RGB images and so you need to include the channel information:

```
images = images.view(-1, 32, 3*32).cuda()
```

This is why your batch is 3x what you expect because it was putting each channel as an element of your batch.

Comment: Original size of images is 32x32 and I didn't change the size. Can you please explain little bit more? Now error is "RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 32, got 96"

Comment: It's an RGB image which means it has 3 channels. When you use the `resize` transform, it ignores the channels and just resizes the height and width of the image, this leaves your image being of shape `[3,32,32]`.  When you batch this data you get a shape of `[batch_size,3,32,32]`. So, when you reshape this for RNN processing, you need to include the `3` channels in your reshape or else it will be appended to the batch dimension.

Comment: To fix your error ,you need to change the input dimension from your RNN to 3x32.

Comment: I have also changed the input dimension but it didn't work out

Comment: What's the new error?

Comment: RuntimeError: Expected hidden size (1, 16, 64), got [1, 64, 64]

Comment: please update your question to reflect the error and new code and put the full stack trace.